# Will I get Offcial updates after rooting my Xperia SP?

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, stock-android

I have Sony Xperia SP, I am planning to root my device. Will I get offcial updates ( Like Kitkat update in future ) after rooting?

Answer (score 0):

No, OTA updates only work with unmodified system images. If you can download a new official system image, you'll still be able to flash that yourself, but you'll probably have to root again after you've done that.

Comment: But I got my update when I am in rooted  `wt19i`. I was  `.431`  build and I got a update of `.587`.But I didn't update however

Comment: Thanks !! I am satisfied with my current image, but it is working slow. I was expecting at least good performance with this expensive device which have 1 GB RAM and nice processor.

Comment: @sameer Usually it'll still offer to install the update, since the app that downloads OTA updates doesn't know the system has been modified. Only when you try to install the update will it fail.

Comment: Yes and we can update via PC companion rite?

Comment: @sameer I don't know about Sony phones in particular, but if there's a non-OTA update method, that will still work.